# Xgboost giving different results on windows and Linux

Tags: xgboost

I'm facing one issue with the results not matching on Windows and Linux. I'm using the same code on both machines. Using separate trains. csv and test. csv
The problem is due to sampling and col_sample_by_tree. When I set the values of both parameters to 1 (i.e., no sampling), the results are the same. But for any value less than 1, I got different results. I tried using a specific random_state value also, but  no effect.
Using the xgboost 1.5.0 version, with the sklearn API

Comment: [Possibly differences in how `long doubles` are formatted.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16744245/same-calculation-on-linux-and-windows-different-results)